# Regex Replace that contains default empty array

Tags: sql, arrays, regex, postgresql, sql-function

I'm trying to create a function that takes a text parameter and an array of text parameter which defaults to an empty array when no second parameter is passed.

I then want to replace any words in the text parameter that also appear in the array of text to be removed. If this array is empty, I don't want to remove anything.

So far, I have this:

```
create or replace function remove_words(name text, words_to_remove text[] default '{}'::text[]) returns text as
$$
    select regexp_replace(name,(select '(' || string_agg(r,'|') || ')' from unnest(words_to_remove) r),'','gi');
$$ language sql immutable parallel safe;
```

At the minute, if I call the function with both parameters, it seems to act as expected:

```
select remove_words('red orange blue green', '{black, brown, green, orange}');

 remove_words 
---------------
 red blue
```

However, if I don't pass through a second parameter, the returned text is blank as opposed to the original value:

```
select remove_words('red orange blue green');
 remove_words 
---------------
```

Can anyone advise on how I can make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take the opposite approach, that is: turn the string to a table of words, then eliminate words that belong to the array.

```
create or replace function remove_words(
    name text, 
    words_to_remove text[] default '{}'::text[]
) returns text as
$$
    select string_agg(word, ' ')
    from unnest(string_to_array(name, ' ')) n(word)
    where not n.word = any (words_to_remove)
$$ language sql immutable parallel safe;
```

You can also use `regexp_split_to_table()` to split the string:

```
create or replace function remove_words2(
    name text, 
    words_to_remove text[] default '{}'::text[]
) returns text as
$$
    select string_agg(word, ' ')
    from regexp_split_to_table(name, ' ') n(word)
    where not n.word = any (words_to_remove)
$$ language sql immutable parallel safe;
```

This properly handles the case when the input array is empty.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bdXr2Q3NqVT6pFpzCoqQ1g/0)**:

```
select remove_words('red orange blue green', '{black, brown, green, orange}');

| remove_words |
| ------------ |
| red blue     |


select remove_words('red orange blue green');

| remove_words          |
| --------------------- |
| red orange blue green |


select remove_words2('red orange blue green', '{black, brown, green, orange}');

| remove_words2 |
| ------------- |
| red blue      |


select remove_words2('red orange blue green');

| remove_words2         |
| --------------------- |
| red orange blue green |
```